# Missing PHP55 while installing php code sniffer

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in symfony2. I'm following a tutorail on udemy. While installing php code sniffer with this formula

```
brew install php-code-sniffer
```

I get this error;

```
Missing PHP53, PHP54, PHP55 or PHP56 from homebrew-php. Please install one of them before   continuing
```

I already installed php55, I don't really know why I'm getting this error..

Comment: go to the part of the script that raises this error, you might know more about the problem

Comment: What's your output of 'php -v' ?

Comment: Here is the output PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used php54 version and it solved my problem. Here is the code that I used;

```
brew install php 54
```

Comment: Note: if you already had PHP pre-installed `then do brew install composer --ignore-dependencies`